# Vue prop passed to a component is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Given the following code, I'm getting "`ReferenceError: myvar is not defined`". Is there any obvious error here? If I run this without jQuery wrapper, it doesn't give me the error anymore but it still doesn't show "Yes" as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/p14tvhap/

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component myvar="1" inline-component>
    <h1 v-if="myvar == 1">Yes</h1>
    <h1 v-if="myvar == 2">No</h1>
  </my-component>
</div>

$(function() {

  Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: ['myvar']
  })

  app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  });
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not set `myvar` in the main instance? when you do `v-if="myvar==1`, it looks for `myvar` in the main instance.

Comment: There will be multiple components all using the same variable name as a config variable. Each component will have a different value for that config variable. I'm trying to somehow initialize the value of a variable at a "start" of a component.

Comment: In which case, then I would create an object like. `{ myvars: { component1var: 1, component2var: 2 ... }}` and then pass it down to the components. You lose the convenience to always use `myvar` though.

Comment: What about defining it inside of "data" on each component https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function?

Comment: The data is still component specific. it's not visible in the parent. Or maybe you can move both `h1` tags inside the component if they belong to the component at the end.

Comment: How can I move them "inside" of the component? Both h1 tags are already wrapped inside of the <my-component> tag, I thought that means they belong to the component?

Comment: When you wrap them inside `my-component`, they are taken as [slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots). You need to create them as templates of the component for them to be part of the component.

Comment: Push in the right direction, thanks. I was using "inline-component" instead of "inline-template" on the <my-component> tag. That was the problem! https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change "inline-component" to "[inline-template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates)" and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

vue props are passed with `:` before it

```
  <my-component :myvar="1" inline-component>
```

Comment: because i thought you are using inline-template just for demonstration purposes. define template inside your component.

Comment: That’s not necessarily true. Adding `:` [dynamically binds props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props), but it’s not necessary to mark something as `prop`.

Comment: actually yes, but why not use always dynamic props